# Indentation problems 3.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, indentation, definition

Here is the code

```
def has_stop(dna,frame) :
   stop_codon_found=False
   stop_codons =['tga','tag','taa']
   for i in range(frame,len(dna),3) : 
      codon =dna[i:i+3].lower()
      if codon in stop_codons:
         stop_codon_found=True
         break
   Return stop_codon_found
```

Python Jupyter notebook turn 'break' in RED. Why? and running it gives "File "", line 10
    Return stop_codon_found
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Well, if I move 'break' one space to the left, leaving the letter b in 'break' sticking out and lining up r in 'break' with s in 'stop_codon_found', break turns GREEN. It of course says "unindent does not match any outer indentation level". If I hit one indentation to the right, 'break' also turns GREEN, but it says 'unexpected indent'

What is going on?

Comment: It sounds like you have a mix of tabs and spaces in your code

Comment: Thank you. I did remove one more manual space on the two lines. Now the RED light is gone when lining up break with the stop_code line above. Good. But the invalid syntax message is the same. And return below is still not turning GREEN

Comment: File "<ipython-input-61-2777721b633a>", line 10
    Return stop_codon_found

Comment: It's ```return``` not ```Return```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def has_stop(dna,frame) :
   stop_codon_found=False
   stop_codons =['tga','tag','taa']
   for i in range(frame,len(dna),3) : 
      codon =dna[i:i+3].lower()
      if codon in stop_codons:
         stop_codon_found=True
         break
   return stop_codon_found
```

In order to have your `return` within the function it has to be one indentation level under `def ...`. Also it's `return` not `Return`

Comment: It is return, not Return. That does it. Thanks.